# Error "No overload for method 'EndExecuteNonQuery' takes 0 arguments"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

While executing the following code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(global::DataBase.Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString);
        try 
        {
            string sql = "INSERT INTO student (stdid,stdname) values("+tid.Text+",N'"+tname.Text+"')";
            SqlCommand exeSql=new SqlCommand(sql,cn);
            cn.Open();

            exeSql.EndExecuteNonQuery(); // <-- Error occurs here

            MessageBox.Show("Add new Record Done||","Message",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            this.studentTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.student);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        { 
             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally 
        { 
            cn.Close();
        }

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.studentTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.student);
    }
}}
```

I got a "No overload for method 'EndExecuteNonQuery' takes 0 arguments" error.

How can I fix this error ?

Comment: Error message is clear. This method has only one overload and it takes one parameter as `IAsyncResult`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.endexecutenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You should learn about SQL injection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection or http://bobby-tables.com

Answer (score 2):

Try using `ExecuteNonQuery()` instead.